# .htacess rewrite condition: page to seconddomain/page

Tags: htaccess

I am using a single WordPress installation for two separate websites with different domains.

To redirect the second domain to its own index page I use.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^seconddomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.seconddomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page_id=78 [NC,QSA]
```

this works great, but I don't know how to do this with specific pages,
for example, the page for the imprint.

The first's page imprint has the permalink firstdomain.com/imprint and the second pages imprint has the permalink firstdomain.com/seconddomain-imprint.

How can I access this page with an URL like:

```
seconddomain.com/imprint
```

Comment: What do you mean by "imprint"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^seconddomain.com$ [OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.seconddomain.com$
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page_id=78 [NC,QSA]
> ```

The "problem" with this is that it rewrites `seconddomain.com/<everything>` to `/index.php?page_id=78`. If you only want the second domain's home page to be served with `page_id=78` then you should change the `RewriteRule` *pattern* to match just the home page (ie. an empty URL-path). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?seconddomain\.com
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?page_id=78 [QSA,L]
```

(I've also combined the two `RewriteCond` directives, escaped the dots and removed the trailing `$` to catch a FQDN. The `NC` flag is also redundant here and the `L` flag is probably preferable to prevent further directives being processed unnecessarily.)

Then, for *specific pages* you would need to duplicate the above directives. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?seconddomain\.com
RewriteRule ^specific-page$ index.php?page_id=NN [QSA,L]
```

Where `NN` is the appropriate `page_id` for `/specific-page`.

If you have many URLs then the directives can be altered to avoid having to include the `RewriteCond` directive every time.